# socket.readLine() reads twice

Tags: sockets, readline

i made a client server chat program but for some reason when i send something to the server or vice versa i recieve an additional empty line

for example if the client said "hello"
the server recieves ....
{
client : hello
client :
}
     these are send and recieve functions

```
public static void send(){
    out.println(message_out);

    }



public void read(){      


    try {
        while(true)
        {

        message_in = in.readLine();

            ConversationBox.append("Client :"+message_in+"\n");

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

   System.out.println("Client disconnected!");
   e.printStackTrace();

    }



}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second reading seems to be null value which causes an exception and end of while loop. Instead you should use the following while loop:

```
while ((message_in = in.readLine()) != null)
    ConversationBox.append("Client :"+message_in+"\n");
```

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect. The null value does not cause an exception or end the while loop in that code.

Answer (score 0):

Your protocol provides no way to uniquely identify the end of a message. If a message is "foo\nbar", you send it as "foo\nbar\n". Since the receiver interpret a newline as a message separator, this will appear to the receive to be two messages, "foo" and then "bar".

If you're going to use a newline as a message separator, you must do one of two things:

1. Ensure no message ever contains a newline.
2. If a message contains a newline, escape it somehow and detect that in the receiver.

Otherwise, the message "Hello\n" will be transmitted as "Hello\n\n" and received as "Hello" followed by an empty message.

Answer (score 0):

well thx David Schwartz , i used

```
if(message_in.isEmpty()){}
else
 ConversationBox.append("Server :"+message_in+"\n");
```

and it's working fine